# What a reason for C2148 or similar errors on another compilers?

Tags: x86-64, integer-overflow

I found interesting problem, and can't find the proper answer:
The error c2148 happens, when you try to create array with 2^31 + 1 elements. Same errors I found in another compilers: Clang, GCC, etc. (Tried on https://godbolt.org/).

Here code example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Boo
{
public:
    double* GetArr() {return arr;}
    const double* GetArr() const {return arr;}
    double arr[100000 * 100000];
private:
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Boo> b = make_shared<Boo>();
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100 * 100; ++i)
    {
            b->arr[i] = i;
            cout << i << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

In this case, I found several compilers(clang until 10.0), that can compile, but when you run program - you get SIGABORT.
So, the question is - that problem is depend on architecture of CPU - and we have limits on assembly level? Or there something else?

Comment: `100000 * 100000` has signed-integer overflow UB, since the type of `100000` is `int`.  Write it as `100000ULL * 100000` or `10000000000ULL` to make the type `unsigned long long` (`size_t` in Windows x64)

Comment: MSVC - same error c2148, Clang, and gcc - if this double - bad_alloc exception, if change array type to char - we back to SIGKILL.